# Can't initiate replica set in Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, mongodb-replica-set

Whenever I type: `rs.initiate()`, I get the following error message:

```
{
    "info2" : "no configuration explicitly specified -- making one",
    "me" : "VMHOSTNAME:27017",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
    "code" : 93
}
```

I'm running under google-cloud-engine with latest MongoDB.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried making a replica set configuration explicitly? It sounds like the autoconfig process is having trouble coming up with a hostname that maps to the node, which is symptomatic of some networking problem.

Answer (score 35):

You could try passing a parameter to the `.initiate()` command.

Like so:

```
rs.initiate({_id:"yourReplSetName", members: [{"_id":1, "host":"yourHost:yourPort"}]})
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks. MongoDB official documentation sucks.

Answer (score 31):

Your VMHOSTNAME must be an alias for 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts file to make it work.

See here https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16157

Comment: In particular, it cannot be an alias for 127.0.1.1 as it is by default on Ubuntu, as pointed out in this answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105035/unable-to-create-replica-set-for-mongodb-in-linux/105088#105088

Answer (score 15):

The problem might be in your mongo config. Look for the following line and comment it out:

```
#bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.
```

Comment: This was the simplest fix on an (Amazon) AWS EC2 instance!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, exactly, or you can change your hostname to something that is already in your /etc/hosts pointing to 127.0.0.1 such as localhost.

With a mac you can do this by typing `sudo scutil –-set HostName localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the VMHOSTNAME in the /etc/hostnames file and the referenced mongo instance is running then its possibly a port number error. In my case it was. Shards tipically started at port 27018.