# MongoServerError: "No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node," How do I fix this?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Started mongo server using

`mongod --port 27018 --dbpath "/usr/local/var/mongodb/data/db0" --replSet rs0 --bind_ip "locahost,0.0.0.0"`

And connected to the instance using

`mongosh mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/vndr`

Tried to initiate a replica set using `rs.initiate()`

Then got the error

```
---
> rs.initiate()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig"
}
```

On the server log noticed these lines saying ""Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local" not known

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-18T14:52:20.861+01:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":21207,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"getaddrinfo() failed","attr":{"host":"Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local","error":"nodename nor servname provided, or not known"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-18T14:52:25.866+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4834700, "ctx":"conn1","msg":"isSelf could not connect via connectSocketOnly","attr":{"hostAndPort":"Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local:27018","error":{"code":6,"codeName":"HostUnreachable","errmsg":"couldn't connect to server Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local:27018, connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local:27018: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-08-18T14:52:25.867+01:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"REPL",     "id":21425,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"replSetInitiate error while validating config","attr":{"error":{"code":74,"codeName":"NodeNotFound","errmsg":"No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node"},"config":{"_id":"rs0","version":1,"members":[{"_id":0,"host":"Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local:27018"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Followed response in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211285/errmsg-no-host-described-in-new-configuration-1-for-replica-set-rs0-maps-to) and added the line `127.0.0.1 Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local` to my `/etc/hosts` file to fix this.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section

127.0.0.1 figmadaemon.com

127.0.0.1 Nnadozies-MacBook-Pro.local
```

Posting this because the similar question wasn't really clear on how to solve the problem. I think this makes it clearer that the hostname mongodb was looking at could not be resolved to an IP address because it wasn't in `/etc/hosts`

Tip on editing `/etc/hosts`: use sudo permissions for write access

Other than that please I'm curious what other way I can run mongodb instances so they use known hostnames.

Comment: ty so much! worked!